# What is the best way to pass context to a singleton class

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, singleton

I have created a singleton class that performs some DB operation, every activity will call this class, and i need to pass context to it.

This is what each activity will do.

```
AnalyticsWrapper analyticsWrapper= AnalyticsWrapper.getInstance();
analyticsWrapper.reportView(MainActivity.this)
```

Now i am little confused about what can go wrong when i am passing activity reference to a singleton class.

I have few questions.

- What is the good way of passing `context` to a long running task.
- Is it better if i pass `getApplicaitonContex()` instead of
  `MainActivity.this` here.
- Will it increase memory, when each activity will be passing its context to singleton class, and it can lead to memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong using application context for DB Singleton, it will likely outlive Activity so passing Activity Context will leak. I've been passing App Context to Database instances for a long time and it never caused any issue with increasing memory or functionality.